# Do I need a ground plane?

Tags: pcb, ground, orcad

I'm a noobie in pcb designing, so i created this one single sided board, do i need do add a ground plane if I have a ground trace?

Cheers![image]

Comment: You have a ground trace? Where? I see plenty of signal traces, but now power and ground traces... I also see a lot (and I men a lot) of spaghetti traces.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle the trace that goes to pin 2

Comment: Pin two of what? Where? Ground and power traces should be considerably fatter than your normal signal traces to keep impedance and resistance low. None of yours are even remotely like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you need a ground plane depends on the frequency of operation of your circuit (which you have not told us). If it's a low-frequency circuit (say, audio frequencies), then you probably don't need a ground plane. But if it's a high-frequency circuit (say, 1MHz or above), then you do need a ground plane.

As the commenters have said, you should make your power and ground traces wider than your signal traces. And since it looks like you have room on the PCB, you should make a ground-fill area, even for a low-frequency board. This means that all the bare PCB area will not be bare insulator, but covered with copper and connected to ground.